# Python Tkinter error entryformartname is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

Main module calls the module which I have posted. I am trying to create a point of sale and this particular code renames the title of the program.

Here is my code:

```
    from Globalvariables import *
    from tkinter import *
    
    #Mart Name
    #user accounts
    
    
    def settingsmain():
    
     settingmenu = Toplevel()
     settingmenu.iconbitmap('D:/Gatlabs logo.ico')
    
     labelformartname = Label(settingmenu, text = "Enter name of your store")
     entryformartname = Entry(settingmenu)
     entryformartname.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    
     setmartname = Button(settingmenu, text = "setname", command = setname)
     setmartname.grid(row= 0, column = 1)
    
    
     settingmenu.mainloop()
    
    
    def setname():
    
        global Mname
        Mname = entryformartname.get()
```

Although I have imported `Tkinter` and created an entry widget, I get error:

```
"NameError: name 'entryformartname' is not defined"
```

Where am I mistaken?

Comment: entryformartname is local variable and only live in settingsmain

Answer (score 1):

As the entryformartname has been defined in a different function and in the line -:

```
Mname = entryformartname.get()
```

you're tryna access it in a different function, it gives the error entryformartname not defined.

Now, as the entryformartname is a local variable of only the specific function where it's defined, so if you wanna use it in some other function or somewhere else generally, you'll have to make it a global var.

It's really simple to make it a global variable. Just use the keyword global like so in the function where it's defined -:

```
global entryformartname # The code is used to declare that entryformartname is a global variable.
```

This should make it global. But still until you've told the other function, that the entryformartname variable you wanna access is global and not local you have to import it into the other function which can be done like so -:

```
global entryformartname # The same code but this time used for importing the global var.
```

So adding these lines in both functions should solve your problem.
Hope it helps
And hope you're safe in the times of an ongoing pandemic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global variable.like:

```
def settingsmain():
    global entryformartname
    settingmenu = Toplevel()
    settingmenu.iconbitmap('D:/Gatlabs logo.ico')

    labelformartname = Label(settingmenu, text="Enter name of your store")
    entryformartname = Entry(settingmenu)
    entryformartname.grid(row=0, column=0)

    setmartname = Button(settingmenu, text="setname", command=setname)
    setmartname.grid(row=0, column=1)

    settingmenu.mainloop()


def setname():
    global Mname,entryformartname
    Mname = entryformartname.get()
```